# Symfony FORMS : diference between {'model' => $this->getRelatedModelName('model')} and {'model'=>'model'} in setWidgets

Tags: php, forms, symfony1, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I've been doing the SYMFONY jobeet tuto(day 10) and once in the FORMS section, I found that some times we use :

```
'category_id'  => new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => $this->getRelatedModelName('JobeetCategory'), 'add_empty' => false)),
```

and sometimes we use simply

```
'jobeet_affiliates_list' => new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('multiple' => true, 'model' => 'JobeetAffiliate')),
```

Can anyboody explain to me WHY? and HOW is it working ?
why ,sometimes,do we use **getRelatedModelName**?? and why somtimes **'model' => 'myModel'**???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much same thing, but, you can only use `getRelatedModelName` when there's a relation between the current form's model and the model you need in your widget. For example, if there's a relation defined between Article and Category, you can use `getRelatedModelName('Category')` in ArticleForm (usually a relation is defined).

In both cases (when a relation exists/does not exist) you can just write the model as a string `'model' => 'JobeetAffiliate'`. I usually do that.

Comment: Thanks Vlad! if i have it right : i should say that in this case JobeetAffiliate must be have a relation with the JobeetAffiliate table in the DB ?

Comment: No. It's about the relation between 2 models, not between a model and it's table. In your first example, you probably have a category table/model and a jobeet_category table/model (most likely the category table primary key is a foreign key in jobeet_category table). So the JobeetCategory has a relation with Category and Category with JobeetCategory. That's why you can you `getRelatedModelName` (you might as well write the exact relation there, fx `'Category'`).